# The population size does not affect the sample size?

Tags: sampling, sample-size

I used the following formula to calculate the sample size.

```
n = Z^2 * K * p * (1-p) / i^2; 
(k = 2, Z = 1.96, p = expected proportion, i = 0.03)
```

I noticed that the sample size is not related to the population size, it means whatever the population size is small or large, the sample size is still the same! I do not assimilate? My idea is that if the population size is important, certainly the size of the sample increases and vice versa.
Is there a requirement to use this formula?

Comment: Formulas of this nature, which are based on several approximations, are applicable when both the following hold: (1) $np$ is not "too small" (a lower threshold of $5$ is usually cited); and (2) the population size is substantially larger than $n$ (how much larger depends on how certain you are about $p$, but we might start being concerned when the population is less than about $10n$). Note that neither of these conditions can be checked until you have actually computed $n$!

Comment: Please do not alter your post in order to respond directly to comments (unless the alterations reflect improvements to the question itself): instead, post comments here.  I have rolled your post back to its original version.  You attempted to say that you are interested in "representativeness," but that's a completely different issue than the questions you originally raised about sample size and population size.  Would you care to clarify this?

Comment: Thank you. If I try to determine the sample size is in order to get an accurate representation of the whole of the target population, in orderto generalize the results to the entire population. A sample is a set of individuals representative of a population.
What I am trying to understand why the size of the population is not included in the formula for calculating of sample size(n = Z² K * p * (1-p) / i²). Because my idée, if  i have a large  size  population certainly, the sample size will be as large and vice versa.

Answer (score 4):

The population size does matter, but, unless the sample size is a large proportion of the population, it matters so little that it can be ignored.

If N is the population size and n is the sample size, then the correction factor is

$
\sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}
$

so, e.g. if you were doing polling for a national election, it would make essentially no difference if you took 300 people from a city, state or country.

This is counterintuitive, but correct.

Comment: is there any particular statistic or measurement where the true population size does matter? I.e., if my sample size is 80% of the true population, wouldn't that be more representative than if my sample size was 20% of the true population? (holding the actual sample size constant across both scenarios)